# Paypal Error 10004 on non-referenced credit using NVP API

Tags: paypal, paypal-nvp

I'm attempting to issue a non-referenced credit to a customer using NVP API. But I keep getting "RESPMSG Field Format error: 10004-This transaction cannot be processed."

I've checked my transaction settings in manager.paypal.com and "Allow Non-Referenced Credits" is set to YES. Also this is a feature that previously worked, but not it does not.

Is there something wrong with my POST?

Here is the RESULT (I've thrown in some returns to make it easy to read.)

```
RESULT=7
&PNREF=BF0P2C4FE25E
&RESPMSG=Field format error: 10004-This transaction cannot be processed.
&HOSTCODE=10004
```

Here is the POST - is there something wrong with it?

```
VENDOR=[masked]
&PARTNER=PayPal
&USER=[masked]
&PWD=[masked]
&TRXTYPE=C
&TENDER=C
&AMT=180.00
&ACCT=[masked]
&EXPDATE=0425
&BILLTOZIP=90049-5013
&BILLTOSTREET=11%20Lake%20Vicente%20Blvd.
&BILLTOFIRSTNAME=Steve
&BILLTOLASTNAME=Lee
&COMMENT1=BA5HOS
&COMMENT2=767049
&INVNUM=967049
&VERBOSITY=HIGH
```